# unable to pass props to components in react-redux

Tags: javascript, components, react-redux, reducers

I'm trying to pass props to multiple components using react-redux. The data that I'm receiving and trying to pass is from a database, so asynchronicity is  involved. Because props isn't defined when it hits the component, my app is throwing an undefined error. After it throws the error in the component, it continues to resolve state, but Once state is defined, it doesn't rerender the component with the new props. Another nugget...I'm using combineReducers. Before using combineReducers (just using the baby-reducer) I didn't have this problem. It started after I made another reducer and combined it with (baby-reducer) Any idea what is going on here? Why won't my component re-render?

Here is my container that is rendering components:

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react'
    import store from '../store'
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import BabyProfile from '../components/BabyProfile'
    import Weight from '../components/Weight'
    import Height from '../components/Height'
    import Feed from '../components/Feed'
    import Sleep from '../components/Sleep'
    import Diaper from '../components/Diaper'


    class BabyProfileContainer extends Component {

      render(){
        // console.log("RENDER PROPS", this.props)
        const  {baby, weight, height, feed, sleep, diapers} = this.props

        return(
          <div>
            <BabyProfile baby={baby}/>
            <Weight weight={weight}/>
            <Height height={height}/>
            <Feed  feed={feed}/>
            <Sleep sleep={sleep}/>
            <Diaper diapers={diapers}/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
      // console.log("MSTP Baby Container", state, "OWN PROPS", ownProps)
      return {
        baby: state.baby,
        diapers: state.diapers,
        weight: state.weight,
        height: state.height,
        sleep: state.sleep,
        feed: state.feeding
      }
    }



    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BabyProfileContainer)
```

here is my baby-reducer:

```
    import {RECEIVE_BABY} from '../constants'


    const initialBabyState = {
      baby: {},
      diapers: [],
      weight: [],
      height: [],
      feeding: [],
      sleep: []

    }

    export default function(state = initialBabyState, action){
    console.log('BABY REducer')

    const newState = Object.assign({}, state)

       switch (action.type){

         case RECEIVE_BABY:
         newState.baby = action.baby;
         newState.diapers = action.diapers
         newState.weight = action.weight;
         newState.height = action.height;
         newState.feeding = action.feeding;
         newState.sleep = action.sleep

         break;




         default:
          return state

       }
       return newState

    }
```

here is my combinedReducer:

```
    import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
    import baby from './baby-reducer'
    import parent from './parent-reducer'



    export default combineReducers({
      baby,
      parent

    })
```

Here is my weight component:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2'


    export default function(weight){


    console.log("IN WEIGHT", weight)
    var weightArr = weight.weight

    const weightData = {
      labels: weightArr.map(instance=>instance.date.slice(0,10)),
      datasets:[{
        label: "baby weight",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        data: weightArr.map(instance =>(instance.weight))
      }]
    }

    const options ={

        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true,
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero:true
                  }
              }],
        yAxes: [{ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
        }
        }]
      }



    return (
      <div className="baby">
        <div>
          <h3>I'm In weight component</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="weight"></div>
        {
        weightArr.map((weight,index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <span>{ weight.weight}</span>
          </div>
        ))

      }
      <div className="Chart">
        <Line data={weightData} width={200} height={200} options={options}/>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
    }
```

Here is my action creator:

```
    import {RECEIVE_BABY} from '../constants'
    import axios from 'axios'



    export const receiveBaby = (baby,weight,height,sleep,diaper,feeding) =>({
      type: RECEIVE_BABY,
      baby: baby,
      weight: weight,
      feeding: feeding,
      height: height,
      sleep: sleep,
      diapers: diaper

    })



    export const getBabyById = babyId => {
      console.log("GET BABY BY ID")
      return dispatch => {
        Promise
          .all([
            axios.get(`/api/baby/${babyId}`),
            axios.get(`/api/baby/${babyId}/weight`),
            axios.get(`/api/baby/${babyId}/height`),
            axios.get(`/api/baby/${babyId}/sleep`),
            axios.get(`/api/baby/${babyId}/diaper`),
            axios.get(`/api/baby/${babyId}/feed`)
          ])
          .then(results => results.map(r => r.data))
          .then(results => {
            console.log("THIS IS RESULTS in Action assadkjasdfkjl;", results)
            dispatch(receiveBaby(...results));
          })
          .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
          })
      };
    };
```

[Here is a snapshot from chrome devTools of the error and the subsequent state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5ENx.png)

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have already defined ```weight``` in your state to be an empty array. But in your screenshot I see the value be ```undefined``` for ```weight```.

If I was in your place I would start by checking if my action is updating the ```weight``` correctly or not. I feel that value which you are passing as parameter to  ```weight``` action is incorrect.

If action works properly, can you share the ```container``` from where you are dispatching the action and your root container where you connect to the store?

Comment: Update your question with your actions. You'll also want to take advantage of the [lifecycle methods in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html).

Comment: hi, I've added both my action creator and my weight component. Harkirat Saluja, I think weight is okay as it is correct in the store, the issue is that my component doesn't rerender after the store updates with state thus props are not being distributed to the weight component (this is true for all my components not just weight).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is linked to the fact that when you combine the reducers you need to include them in the `mapStateToProps` in the following way:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
      // console.log("MSTP Baby Container", state, "OWN PROPS", ownProps)
      return {
        baby: state.parent.baby,
        diapers: state.parent.diapers,
        ...
      }
    }
```

Basically, you have to make sure the appropriate reducer is connected here.